# How to compare two tags with git?

Tags: git

I would like to do a diff between two tags and committed changes between those two tags. Could you please tell me the command?

Answer (score 971, accepted):

```
$ git diff tag1 tag2
```

or show log between them:

```
$ git log tag1..tag2
```

sometimes it may be convenient to see only the list of files that were changed:

```
$ git diff tag1 tag2 --stat
```

and then look at the differences for some particular file:

```
$ git diff tag1 tag2 -- some/file/name
```

A tag is only a reference to the latest commit 'on that tag', so that you are doing a diff on the commits between them.

(Make sure to do `git pull --tags` first)

Also, a good reference: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Comment: @kaiser lol! btw, I would like to add this tip to compare whole directories from within `git gui` at "tools/add" like `git difftool -d $REVISION`! and to link [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2006241/1422630) too

Comment: Is there a way to make the `git log` command only show additional commits, not shared commits?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai that is what this command does, it shows the additional commits on tag2 since tag1.

Comment: In my use, it showed all shared commits and additional commits without any distinction between the 2.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: perhaps you are looking for the `--cherry` argument.

Comment: Also useful: simply `git diff tag1` gives differences between tag1 and working directory; `git diff tag1 HEAD` differences between tag1 and most recent commit.

Comment: And: `gitk` (or `gitg`) makes browsing commits between tags easy.

Comment: `git diff tag1 tag2 --stat=1000` by adding `=1000` you allow the file names to show in their entirety

Comment: if you want to just see the list of files changed its `--name-only` before the two

Comment: Why do I need `--` there? It also works without.

Comment: To signal that what follows should be interpreted as path, not a tag or something else.

Answer (score 15):

If source code is on Github, you can use their comparing tool: https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/

Comment: is there any way to do this without the 250 commit limit?

Answer (score 7):

For a side-by-side visual representation, I use `git difftool` with `openDiff` set to the default viewer.

Example usage:

```
git difftool tags/<FIRST TAG> tags/<SECOND TAG>
```

If you are only interested in a specific file, you can use:

```
git difftool tags/<FIRST TAG>:<FILE PATH> tags/<SECOND TAG>:<FILE PATH>
```

As a side-note, the `tags/<TAG>`s can be replaced with `<BRANCH>`es if you are interested in `diff`ing branches.

Answer (score 2):

As @Nakilon said, their is a comparing tool built in **github** if that's what you use.

To use it, **append the url of the repo with "/compare"**.

Comment: is there any way to do this without the 250 commit limit?

Answer (score 1):

Number of insertions/deletions between 2 tags (combine all commits between tags, for example, 1 file was changed/committed 6 times between tags)

```
git log --numstat --format='' v1.0..v1.1 | awk '{files += 1}{ins += $1}{del += $2} END{print "total: "files" files, "ins" insertions(+) "del" deletions(-)"}'
total: 6 files, 57 insertions(+) 12 deletions(-)
```

diff between tags, for example, diff of the same file at tag v1.0 and at v1.1

```
 git diff --shortstat v1.0 v1.1
 1 file changed, 50 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
```

Just to show that stats for `diff` (kind of similar to `vimdiff`), and for all commits in between are different.