# Git diff between latest and previous tag

Tags: git, git-diff, git-tag

I want to do a diff just like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211809/git-diff-between-given-two-tags).

The only difference is that i don't want to inform the tag names 'manually' i want them to be retrieved by git commands.

I know that `git describe --tags` returns my latest tag. But what about the previous one? How to get it?

Basically what i want is:

```
$ git diff $(git_command_to_get_previous_tag) $(git describe --tags)
```

And what i don't want:

```
$ git diff 1.0 2.0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the latest tag using:

```
git tag --sort version:refname | tail -n 1
```

And the previous tag using:

```
git tag --sort version:refname | tail -n 2 | head -n 1
```

Putting it together, you can get a diff using this:

```
git diff $(git tag --sort version:refname | tail -n 2 | head -n 1) $(git tag --sort version:refname | tail -n 1)
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks ! The command is a little longer than i expected but there's no problem there :)

Comment: how could it be work on windows ? tail command is not recognized on windows.

Comment: @VedankKulshrestha you can do almost the same thing in PowerShell: `git diff tags/$(git tag -l --sort=-version:refname v* | select -first 1) tags/$(git tag -l --sort=-version:refname v* | select -first 2 | select -last 1) --name-only`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same, but with PowerShell instead of Bash. The general method is the same though.

Fetch all tags in case there are new ones:

`git fetch --all --tags`

Get the latest tag using:

`git tag -l --sort=-version:refname | select -first 1`

Get the previous tag using:

`git tag -l --sort=-version:refname | select -first 2 | select -last 1`

Put it together:

`git diff $(git tag -l --sort=-version:refname | select -first 1) $(git tag -l --sort=-version:refname | select -first 2 | select -last 1)`

My actual example use case:

`git fetch --all --tags > $null; git diff tags/$(git tag -l --sort=-version:refname v* | select -first 1) tags/$(git tag -l --sort=-version:refname v* | select -first 2 | select -last 1) --name-only | Select-String -Pattern ".*\.xml" | Write-Host`

This will get all remote tags in case there are new ones, redirecting output to $null so it does not show up, get the list of files changed between the most recent tags that start with `v`, then filter the list of files to only return those that end in `.xml`