# how git print newly added code since tags

Tags: git

The place where I work values code security so much that we go through a security check every time before we publish the product. Unfortunately we have over one million LOC, thus those work became really some kind of torment.

For clarity, sometimes we check the code in this way:

`find . -regex '.*\.java\|.*\.jsp'|xargs egrep -inr "(?:SAXParser|SAXParserFactory|DocumentBuilderFactory|TransformerFactory|XMLReader|DOMParser)"|tee ../result_xml.file`

I planned to sort these result_xxx.file and next time when excuting the same find command we could sort and compare these two files and extract those new bad code. But it sucks.

Since we are using git and most of our code are Java and JavaScript, I wonder whether there is a way to collect the new added or modified code since last time we finished the scrutiny(with git tag) like

`git log --code --since #lastTag
git log --code --between #thisTag #thatTag`

I've searched for this but got no helpful information. Anyone got better ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: There are software solutions that will scan your code for security vulnerabilities. Just use one of those within your continuous integration build process. If you don't have a CI process, then get one

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211809/git-diff-between-given-two-tags

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an idea, could we do this with git web hook feature? Recently I finished a plugin based on the git web hook feature. Every time we push or propose a merge request, the plugin(which developed for Intellij Idea) will perform an notification. But here is the problem, the git web hook interface provides json string but I can't find the code inside it. Anyway I can get the code we commited?

## updated

I found a useful command:

`git log -p`

Sorry, I seldom use the command directly cause Idea works with git so well. 
Command `git log` also support `--since` feature which could be followed by a time param. Two things still left to do:

1. Format the `git log -p` and get the added or modified lines, could be done by checking what the line starts with.
2. Save the time and next time we could add this `time` to git log command like:

   `git log --since lastTime -p`

In this way we could scan the code incrementally. A lot of details need to be clarified, got work to do...