# Upgrading Laravel from 9 to 10. Update files outside of vendor folder

Tags: php, laravel, git, composer-php, laravel-10

I want to upgrade my already existing Laravel 9 project to Version 10. The goal is, that not only the vendor files update through composer. Additionally I want to reflect the changes in my project's code **outside the vendor folder** as well.

I followed the [Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade) of the Laravel Documentation to upgrade my project.

[Here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/compare/9.x...10.x) are the files, that have been changed.

E.g. my `app/Console/Kernel.php` should change from

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

to

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     */
    protected function commands(): void
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a git-related question

Comment: Maybe, I don't know. It feels like I just need to `git pull` something but I don't know

Comment: You have to manually change the files, because you could have changed anything so you will have a massive amount of git merge issues, still you can't use git, manually doit or use laravel shift

Comment: Why not read their upgrade guide? Do you have any **specific** question about this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes to the Laravel new app skeleton can be viewed on Github via their compare tool: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/compare/9.x...10.x

(You can do this locally, using a GUI Git client [or the Git command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211809/how-to-compare-two-tags-with-git), as well.)

These changes can be turned into a `.patch` file, which you can then use to apply to *your* app. Github again provides a fairly easy way to do this; https://github.com/laravel/laravel/compare/9.x...10.x.patch.

Once you have a .patch file saved locally, you can apply it within your repo using `git apply <path-to-patch-file>`. In most cases, this should apply cleanly.

<sup>This is, to be clear, not a replacement for following the full upgrade guide at https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade, as it will only make the tweaks necessary for the default app skeleton; it will not update your own code you wrote *in* Laravel in any way.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Updating these kind of "example" files automatically may not be possible automatically at all since they are editable by users in their projects, that's why they're not in vendor.

Your best bet for updating PHP-related syntax, such as mentioned type hints, may be something like PHP-CS-Fixer with appriopriate rules, but your example of functions wouldn't work with that as that requires old way of defining return types through PHPDoc.

Copying these changes manually from Laravel repository and adjusting them to your code, if you modified those files, is the way to go.

Comment: Understand. So the two possibilities I have are 1) manually 1 by 1 or 2) pay (or build something shift-like myself, where I'd better stick with 1  Isn't there something like `git merge the code from Laravel's github` or something like that? I don't want to check every single change. I want to merge everything like I would have started from a fresh new Laravel 10 project

Comment: That's what composer does. It merges the source code from Laravel into vendor folder of your project, as you noticed. But you need to adjust your project is there are breaking changes.

Comment: That's what my question is about. The Laravel Repo (https://github.com/laravel/laravel) has all theses changes. I could download it as a zip, copy it in my project and replace the files. and git would show me the differences, or what has been removed. But a merge would be better.

Comment: I would recommend having a read about how `composer.json`, `composer.lock` and `vendor` work. E.g. here https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md As these questions don't make much sense if it's not about breaking changes - the most basic Composer/package manager knowledge is recommended to upgrade libraries in your project. In short: you should never have vendor files in your repo

Comment: I think you don't understand my question. I know how composer works and I know that composer updates inside the vendor folder. But what I want, e.g. my `app/Console/Kernel.php` `protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)` should change to `protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) : void`, because this is what you would have, if you install Laravel 10 fresh. This has nothing to do with composer in my eyes.

Comment: That would have been a lot better description with an example initially - I would recommend updating the question. But my initial answer kind of covers it, although from a bit different angle - it's changes you need to do manually. This example is basically just adding a return type to some functions and it's more related to PHP than Laravel.

Comment: Thank you for the tipp. I updated my question accordingly to add more clarity.

Comment: "It's up to you" is not something you should start your answer with. Provide precise instructions about how to resolve a problem

Comment: Great! Note that updating these kind of  "example" files automatically may not be possible automatically at all since they are editable by users in their projects, that's why they're not in vendor. Your best bet for updating PHP-related syntax may be something like PHP-CS-Fixer with appriopriate rules, but your example of functions wouldn't work with that as that requires old way of defining return types through PHPDoc.

Comment: @Nico Haase the answer was accurate because it mentioned following changes manually - nothing else you can add there... Wording nitpicking doesn't bring anything IMO. But I'm editing the answer to reflect the actual question now.

Comment: The original answer didn't mention a single **specific** step