# How can I restore files before a certain commit in GitHub?

Tags: github

How can I restore files before a certain commit in GitHub?

Comment: The two very different answers below suggest that you might want to clarify what you want to happen :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to retrieve an individual file from before the commit `f4l4fe1`, for example, you can do:

   ```
   git checkout f4l4fe1^ -- some/file.txt
   ```

   (When you add a `^` to a ref in git, it means the parent of that commit.)  You should find `some/file.txt` back in your working tree, but note that it will also be staged as a change to commit.
2. If you want to just see the working tree as it was on the previous commit, you can check out the commit as if it were a branch:

   ```
   git checkout f4l4fe1^
   ```

   That puts you into a state known as "detached HEAD" where you're no longer on a particular branch, so making new commits won't advance any branch.  To get back to `master`, say, you'd just do `git checkout master`.
3. As a third option, suppose you want to extract a whole directory from that commit, or a whole subdirectory, you can use `git archive` and pipe the output to `tar`, as explained in: [What's the best way to extract a tree from a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364575/whats-the-best-way-to-extract-a-tree-from-a-git-repository)