# How to get files and content by SHA of commit

Tags: git

How to list files that are changed in specific commit and get content of that files when I have sha number of commit ?

Comment: The first part is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/424071/223092 and the second part is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/610208/223092 (probably among many others)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To list the files that were changed by a particular commit, you can do:

```
git show --name-only <commit>
```

If you want to suppress the log message from that output, you can add `--pretty=format:` to the options.

As for your second question, to see the content of a particular file from that commit, say with SHA1sum `f414f31`, you can do:

```
git show f414f31:Documentation/help.txt
```

... where the path `Documentation/help.txt` is relative to the top level of the working tree, regardless of whether you're in a subdirectory or not.  If you need to extract a whole subdirectory, have a look at this question and answer:

- [What's the best way to extract a tree from a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3364575/223092)