# Fatal error after git reset hard

Tags: git

I had a old project which I wanted to add git to.
I run

`git init`

and after that I added .gitignore file.
The error I did is that I haven't commit anything first but I wanted to see if my gitignore file works so I run

```
git add .
```

I noticed that there are more files I wanted to exclude (whole project is 45GB with assets) so I run

```
git reset --hard
```

and this mess up my whole repo.
I lost all of the files except the ones listed in gitignore and I cannot do anything.

```
git status
```

shows me a files listed in git ignore and if I run

```
git reflog
```

or even

```
git log
```

I have this error

```
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
```

Please let me know how can I restore my project?

Comment: possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/q/9750049/7926064 - sorry for your loss. Do you have filesystem snapshots maybe?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen git keep everything as SHA hash which I'm sure you can restore somehow (the project size shows that the files are there). Maybe there is some way I can get the files from the hash even if I need to do it manually file by file?

Comment: You're right, git add added all the files to the repository, however it didn't add a commit object. You can possibly fake a commit object unless you want to go digging manually. If you check the .git\objects folder you'll find all your files in a compressed manner (there may even be packfiles with some of the stuff), but it's going to be a bit of work to restore. See if there are plumbing commands.

Comment: @Greg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791533/unstaged-files-gone-after-git-reset-hard/25792257#25792257

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen do you know how can I do? I'm not git expert.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364575/whats-the-best-way-to-extract-a-tree-from-a-git-repository - for a way to read the index from a tree object and check it out, it may work for you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert on the plumbing commands. Seeing as you don't have a single commit, any tree objects which are not referred to by other tree objects is probably going to be the root tree.

Comment: and do create a backup of the whole folder now :)

Comment: @BNT I'm doing that now, thanks. Once done I try so of the above suggestion.

Comment: Looks like the tree objects are not created until you create the commit.

Comment: You can’t reset on a branch with no commits.

Comment: Thanks Guys. I manage to find a back up so I'm ok.