# Git diff output to file preserve coloring

Tags: git

Is it possible to do `git diff` and save the output to a file with the coloring somehow?

I know how to do `git diff > filename.rtf` - which saves to a file, but I'd like to preserve the coloring.

Comment: You can convert to html with color: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013091/coloured-diff-to-html

Comment: Notepad++ will highlight the file if you save it with the .diff extension.

Answer (score 234):

Try:

```
git diff --color > foo.txt
```

Then later issue:

```
cat foo.txt
```

Or:

```
less -R foo.txt
```

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration:

> Git automatically colors most of its output, but there’s a master
> switch if you don’t like this behavior. To turn off all Git’s colored
> terminal output, do this:
>
> $ git config --global color.ui false
>
> The default setting is auto, which colors output when it’s going
> straight to a terminal, but omits the color-control codes when the
> output is redirected to a pipe or a file.
>
> You can also set it to always to ignore the difference between
> terminals and pipes. You’ll rarely want this; in most scenarios, if
> you want color codes in your redirected output, you can instead pass a
> --color flag to the Git command to force it to use color codes. The default setting is almost always what you’ll want.

Comment: @RoR, one person's "gibberish" is another person's (well, terminal's) color codes. ;-) I tried it and it works; the coloring is preserved if I `cat` the file from the command-line. (How else would you expect the colors to be preserved?)

Comment: Well that's what it does. Adds bash coloring codes. If you cat the file in the console it shows the colors.

Comment: @RoR You'd have to put something in the middle there to convert the bash color codes to rtf format.

Comment: Notepad++ can highlight diff files. (*.diff extensions are automatically highlighted, otherwise change `Language --> D --> Diff`.) If you don't like default colors, change them in `Settings --> Style Configurator --> Diff`. To copy paste with colors you can use a plugin (e.g. `NppExport`) that allows exporting/copying into RTF or HTML.

Comment: git diff A B > foo.diff (Many editors will open the file with the colors because the file is a .diff file)

Comment: Is there a way to export the git diff to wiki markup (with colors)

Comment: `--color` works, does not seem to be well documented, I've done `man -K -- '--color'` and found no `git`, only place I found it documented is **one** mention in https://git-scm.com/book (can be downloaded too, CC license).

Answer (score 80):

Save the file with a .diff extension and open it in Notepad++ or Vim or SublimeText.

```
git diff > 20150203_someChanges.diff
```

Thanks @Monsingor

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know NPP had this syntax!

Comment: the best answer I found so far it  works also with VS Code

Answer (score 23):

Open the output diff file in [Sublime Text 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text#Version_2). It shows the diff colors.

Comment: You might need to change syntax to diff to enable proper highlighting in case the diff file has extension different from *.diff. (via View -> Syntax -> Diff).

Comment: It doesn't highlight `diff.txt` for me, even with automatically detected "Diff" in the right bottom corner.

Answer (score 20):

To expand on @Gabe's answer.

You can pipe the output to an ansi to html converter bash script and direct that output to an html file:

```
git diff --color|./ansi2html.sh > changes.html
```

of course html can be viewed by any browser so output can be read in Windows etc.

ansi2html code is here: http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ansi2html.sh

Comment: doesn't work I get: gawk: cmd. line:25: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: attempt to use array `a (from span)' in a scalar context

Comment: Get Homebrew and run `brew install gawk`. You'll also need `brew install gnu-sed`.

Comment: exactly what i want, awesome !

Comment: The ansi2html python library did it for me https://github.com/ralphbean/ansi2html. pip installable and works exactly as the bash script in this answer. Don't forget to replace "./ansi2html.sh" with "ansi2html".

Comment: In Debian-like, install [kbtin](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=kbtin) and type `git diff --word-diff --color commit1 commit2 | ansi2html > changes.html`.

Answer (score 8):

Vim colors files containing git diff's beautifully.

[image: git diff]

Answer (score 5):

I found an answer here: [Color output of specific git command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107594/color-output-of-specific-git-command).

You can pass `-c color.ui=always` to any `git` command and it will keep coloring on redirection. For example: `git -c color.ui=always status > file`

Answer (score 3):

to allow any colorized terminal text ... git diff or any other ... to be viewable from a browser

```
sudo apt-get install aha  #  https://github.com/theZiz/aha
```

install `aha` using above then issue

```
git diff --color mysourcefile  | aha > ~/cool_colorized.html

firefox  ~/cool_colorized.html
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to file redirection, you also have the [`git diff --output`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---outputltfilegt) option

```
git diff --color --output=aFile
cat aFile
# you would still see the colors
```

---

However, make sure to not use the combined diff format ([for diff on merge commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29290763/6309)), like `git diff -c` or `git diff --cc`

With Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), certain diff options (including `--output`) are currently ignored when combined-diff is shown; mark them as incompatible with the feature.

See [commit cfb19ae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cfb19ae05f4565bc9d0a0cb3a23a3d2ab9fb8fab), [commit e3d1be4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e3d1be4237b831b517a54c70ae3c4ec3840345a4) (18 Jun 2022) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a2d1f00](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a2d1f00bdd79e3059e6a819c0f65e8071e39dac8), 11 Jul 2022)</sup>

> ### [`combine-diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cfb19ae05f4565bc9d0a0cb3a23a3d2ab9fb8fab): abort if --output is given
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> The code for combined diffs currently only writes to stdout.
> Abort and report that fact instead of silently ignoring the `--output` option.
> The (empty) output file has already been created at that point, though.

The error message would therefore be:

```
combined diff and '--output' cannot be used together
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git remote add -f b path/to/repo_b.git
git remote update
git diff master remotes/b/master > foo.txt
```

> Differences extracted in '*.txt' files are easily read by SublimeText2 without the need to set (via View -> Syntax -> Diff).

Comment: `git remote rm remotes/b/master` to reset branch back to it's original state.

Answer (score 0):

You could upload to GitHub and provide a link to the relevant commit.