# Color output of specific git command

Tags: git

I'm writing a tool that runs git commands and captures the output, and I'd like to have the output colored. Git notices that the tool isn't a terminal, so the `color.ui` would need to be set to `always`. I don't really want to set this in the global/repo configuration file, as it would mess with other programs using git. The [git book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-1.html) explicitly discourages that, too:

> You’ll rarely want color.ui = always. In most scenarios, if you want color codes in your redirected output, you can instead pass a --color flag to the Git command to force it to use color codes. The color.ui = true setting is almost always what you’ll want to use.

Sadly, not all git commands support the `--color` flag, most notably `git status` and `git pull`.

So, how do I force colors for one git command? Is there a configuration variable I can set, e.g. for a custom git config file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`-c` option](http://git-scm.com/docs/git#_options) to override config values. This works for all git commands. For example:

```
git -c color.ui=always status > status_file
```

outputs the color codes into the file. It does not see a pty, so it will not try to paginate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [a master/slave PTY](http://code.google.com/p/thebends/source/browse/misc/openpty-example.c?spec=svn133&r=133) to communicate with `git` subcommand instead of a pipe. This makes git think that it runs in an interactive session, not in a pipeline.

Comment: That looks very promising, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: It seems like the best solution, but unfortunately I can't get it work right now in node.js (there's [pty.js](https://github.com/chjj/pty.js), but that is not yet compatible with node v0.11). Thank you anyway!

Comment: Well, I see :-). Nevertheless I guess you can issue a simple native call using e.g. [node-ffi](https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi). Or extend a bit [node-posix](https://github.com/melor/node-posix). Afterall, you need a simple call which would return you a couple of `int`s