# Github save diff to a file and share

Tags: git

I have a private Git repo that I cannot make public.
I like to generate diff from my commits and ask outsider if my commits are good. To make him review my commit easy, I like color (red/green) to be applied to where my changes are. How can I save diff to a file?

Comment: `git diff > changes.diff` - if you use the `.diff` extention, some editors will give you the color highlighting - `.patch` may also work - depends on what you're using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Diff output to file preserve coloring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706492/git-diff-output-to-file-preserve-coloring)

Answer (score 8):

"git format-patch HEAD~" creates a diff for the last commit that you can send through email or as a file.

You can see more options on: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch

Answer (score 0):

print the diff between previous and current version into a file:

```
git diff HEAD^ > /tmp/mypatch
```

apply the changes to current working directory/branch:

```
git apply /tmp/mypatch
```

create a "patch" file out of the diff between previous and current version:

```
git format-patch HEAD^    # creates a file like "0001-descriptiong-of-last-commit.path
```

print each patch to a seperate file, e.g. to send it per mail...

```
git format-patch master
```

[a]pply [m]ailbox to git repo (e.g. `git checkout -b myTestFromMailbox`)

```
git am myPatchMailbox.mbox
```

**difference between `git apply` and `git am`**

`git apply` - takes a patch (e.g. the output of git diff) and applies it to the working directory (or index, if --index or --cached is used).

`git am` - takes a mailbox of commits formatted as an email messages (e.g. the output of git format-patch) and applies them to the current branch.  (git am uses git apply behind the scenes, but does more work before (reading a Maildir or mbox, and parsing email messages) and after (creating commits).)