# Git diff/copy of stashed branch against/to current branch

Tags: git, diff

I am working on branch `XYZ`. I want to know how `foo.c` in this branch compares with `stash{0}` on `master`. Something like

```
git diff master@stash@{0} foo.c
```

which does not work. Now I want that stashes `foo.c` to replace my local file. Something like

```
git checkout master@stash@{0} foo.c
```

**Edit:** I did not realize that stashes aren't owned by a branch, but the stash itself identifies which branch it is a stash of. Problem solved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git diff against a stash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677736/git-diff-against-a-stash)

Comment: another possible duplicate [Git: how to diff the same file between two different commits on the same branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338126/git-how-to-diff-the-same-file-between-two-different-commits-on-the-same-branch), although that talks about diffing on the same branch, it'll work across branches.

Comment: This is how you check out file from another commit (in your case stash): [How do I revert one file to the last commit in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692246/how-do-i-revert-one-file-to-the-last-commit-in-git)

Comment: @ROM those two duplicates you mention are diffing within the same branch right? I want to diff _between_ branches, and actually the stash of one branch. Isn't that different?

Comment: @ROM ahhhh now I see why you say that. I just installed `gitg` which made it obvious to me that stashes are not subobjects of a branch but rather have an attribute indicating the branch they were stashed from!

Comment: Yeah, at the end of the day they are all just commits with IDs.  Git lets you compare any two commits, regardless of branch.  You can also check out any mix of files from any branch into your working copy if you'd like.  Whether that's an appropriate thing to do or not is up to you to decide.