# Diff branches in Atlassian Stash

Tags: git, version-control, diff, git-branch, bitbucket-server

I am trying to get a diff between two branches in stash. Specially before sending the pull request, wanted to verify the changes.

have been reading many articles trying to figure out a solution but haven't succeeded yet.

here are the articles I have looked into:

[Git diff against a stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677736/git-diff-against-a-stash)
[Compare and Diff for Branches](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-3276)

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, the only way to compare branches in Atlassian Stash is to create a pull request first. Otherwise, you can use local git commands to compare arbitrary commits or branches.

This is something we plan to improve in a future release. You can watch for updates [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-3276).

Edit: Since Stash 3.0 it is possible to compare branches directly in Stash

Comment: ...and here's a link to instructions on how to do it: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Stash+3.0+release+notes#Stash3.0releasenotes-Branchcomparisons

Answer (score 1):

Do a `git stash list` to get the list of stashes. Then pick the ones you need to diff and use `git diff` on those two stashed changes

For example

```
~/> git stash list
stash@{0}: On XXX: temp1
stash@{1}: On XXX: temp
~/> git diff stash@{0} stash@{1}
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying to find a way that I can see the diff on stash web interface but could not. Seems like your solution is the only one.

Comment: Why was the answer down voted and the actual subject line changed?

Comment: Someone probably didn't realize that the question was a bit ambiguous in the first revision. This is a perfectly valid answer to the way the _original_ question was interpreted.