# Save stashed files into another folder

Tags: git, git-stash

I have 5 files (mostly .config files) has been stashed from Branch A.
Now, I switched to Branch B. Before I apply stash from A to B, I would like to export as separate files, and browse them with a text editor.

Is it possible to export stashed files into another directory?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677736/git-diff-against-a-stash) for different ways to view a stash.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen looks like he wants to see differences to original file. That I can already do. I want to export entire file with changes applied to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option here at your disposal is `git stash branch`, which creates, and then checks out, a new branch starting from the commit at the stash:

```
git stash branch tempbranch
```

From the branch `tempbranch` you can copy whatever files you want.  When you are finished with the branch, simply delete it and you are done.