# git diff for a single file in stash

Tags: git, git-stash

I know from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677736/git-diff-against-a-stash) how to show the diff against a stash.

```
git stash show -p stash@{1}
```

But how can I show the diff to a specific file from a stash?

Comment: You can also use `git diff stash@{1}`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the diff command with a path:

```
git diff stash@{1} -- <path>
```

Comment: It looks like you don't need the `--`. i.e. the following works for me: `git diff stash@{1} <path>`

Comment: @PaulMasri-Stone Re `--`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321458/meaning-of-git-checkout-double-dashes, for example.

Answer (score -3):

Ru following commands:

1. `git stash list`

   This will return the stash list like

   stash@{0}: WIP on registration_branch: c50163e Error handlers added.

   stash@{1}: WIP on registration_branch: c50163e Error handlers added.
2. `git diff stash@{0}`

   It will return git differences for `stash@{0}`