# Git - Changes made in meld (as the difftool) not saved

Tags: git, git-diff, meld

I followed Jörg W Mittag's answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006032/view-differences-of-branches-with-meld) and have configured meld as the difftool in my git. Now I can view and compare differences of a file in different branches perfectly with this command:

```
git checkout branch1
git difftool branch1:file.f90 branch2:file.f90
```

I executed the above command, made and saved changes in meld. However, when I check the file using:

```
emacs file.f90
```

The changes I made earlier in meld are not saved at all. I don't understand why this is so; I must have not entirely correctly configured meld as the diff tool. Could any one help me with this problem? Thanks!!

Answer (score 10):

To avoid the need to specify the filename twice, use the following:

```
git difftool branch -- file
```

This will compare `branch:file` with `file` in the working tree.

Furthermore, to diff the entire working tree with `branch`, use:

```
git difftool --dir-diff branch
```

As mentioned in other answers, if you need to diff `branch` with `other_branch` (some branch different from what is currently checked out), you must first check out `other_branch` before using the above commands.

Comment: Excellent answer @Mark, this is the simplest command to perform this task. Thank you!

Comment: note: when I used `git difftool -t --dir-diff branch .`, and I changed files from `meld` in working directory and saved them, git (in the same directory, but a different terminal), did NOT report ANY changes with `git status`, until AFTER `meld` gets closed! (this is for git/meld inside MSYS2 shell in Windows 10)

Answer (score 8):

Because you have explicitly given the branches of both files to be diff'ed, meld is working on temporary copies of both files. Try just giving the name of the non-checked out branch:file; this should cause meld to compare a temporary copy of the given branch:file with the checked out file of the same name.

Answer (score 7):

In order to have your changes saved you need to compare some branch to the current working file.

In your case:

```
git checkout branch1
git difftool branch2:file.f90 file.f90
```

Alternatively, you can compare whole branch with the working dir and save your changes too. I have provided more details about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22535996/2178047