# Using meld as difftool for git but listing all files in one window

Tags: git, git-config, meld, difftool, git-difftool

I want to use meld as my diff tool for git.

If I configure my `.gitconfig` like this :

```
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[diff]
    tool = meld
```

and run command : `$ git difftool`
then git open a meld window for each file which have changes.

But I want one single window with all my files in the meld list box.
I have read a little about `-d` or `--dir-diff` option.
When I try : `$ git difftool -d`
then a single windows is opened with one directory tree in each meld part, but either contain empty directories.
I can not open my files from here.

[image]

For infomation :

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.1
$ meld --version
meld 1.8.4
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
```

I am using `git svn` too, but I don't think this is related in my problem; because as far as I understand git-svn, my directory work as a simple git directory.

Related questions  :
[View differences of branches with meld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006032/view-differences-of-branches-with-meld)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I fixed my problem by removing meld and use a new version (3.12.3) of it:
`sudo apt-get remove meld`

Now my `.gitconfig` is like :

```
[difftool]
    prompt = false

[diff]
    tool = meld
    guitool = meld

[difftool "meld"]
    path = /home/me/App/meld/meld-3.12.3/bin/meld
```

And the result from the folowing commands are :

- `git diff` : terminal diff of each modified files
- `git diff <myfile>` : terminal diff of `<myfile>`
- `git difftool <myfile>` : meld diff of `<myfile>`
- `git difftool` : meld diff of each modified files, one bye one
- `git difftool -d` : meld diff of each file, into a single window

I have also add this line to my `bash_alias` but I think it could work without.
`alias meld='/home/benjamin/Applications/meld/meld-3.12.3/bin/meld'`

Comment: for this one:
[difftool "meld"]
    path = /home/me/App/meld/meld-3.12.3/bin/meld
I tried this in the command to know where is meld installed: whereis meld
and it is /usr/bin/meld

Comment: As this question is always viewed, with Ubuntu LTS 18.04, a simple `sudo apt-get install meld`, `git config --global diff.tool meld` and `git difftool -d` should work.

Comment: This is perfect. It works as expected. Thanks!!.
do you use meld for merging, rebase and conflict resolution?

Comment: @ininprsr Yes. `git difftool -d` for a diff. `git mergtool` to resolve a conflict.