# GIT: Find and merge common file differences between branches

Tags: git, merge, diff

I have two branches, one being the master and the other being a development branch.

I would like to see the differences between the two branches, but namely only the files that they have in common and out of those common files, only the files that have been changed in the development branch.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822811/differences-in-git-branches) got me part way there, although it seems to be also showing me new files added into the dev branch that the master does not have.

Once I know the common files that have been changed, I then want to merge those changes in common files from the dev branch back into the master branch.

The reason for this is that I made some small changes to code in the dev branch that should have been made in a separate branch and merged back into master.

Thanks for your help.