# Is there a way to get a visual diff on two branches in SourceTree?

Tags: git, git-branch, atlassian-sourcetree

Does Sourcetree offer a way to visualize differences between `git` branches?

I'm looking for:

- names of files that have changed
- diffs between these files

Answer (score 309, accepted):

Use <kbd>⌘</kbd> (OSX) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (Windows and Linux) and choose any two commits you like in log view. It does not matter what branch the commits belong to.

As a result you will see something like...

> Displaying all changes between f03a18bf0370c62bb5fb5c6350589ad8def13aea and 4a4b176b852e7c8e83fffe94ea263042c59f0548

...down below.

Comment: That was the intuitive thing to do and I tried it. For some reason it isn't working on version: 2.1 on Mavericks 10.9.5. Odd, the command below seems to be working.

Comment: For anyone dense like me, CMD = Command ⌘.  The answer is basically suggesting if you multi-select any two commits, Sourcetree automatically shows you the difference.  I prefer Gan's answer, but if this is more general-purpose.

Comment: Was about tho ask the same thing for **GitKraken, where it turns out to work similarly**.

Comment: Awesome. Works even if one branch is local and the other is the remote I'm about to force-push to

Comment: This doesn't show a branch diff if you've recently merged one into the other, only recent commits between the selections and not the whole branch

Comment: With Mercurial, what you call Log View is called History View instead.

Answer (score 250):

Another way to do this is to right-click on a branch and select the "Diff against current" context menu command (*current* refers to the branch you are currently working on). This will give you the diff between the head commits of the two branches.

Source: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/167126/sourcetree-diff-against-current-behavior#

Screenshot (based on Sourcetree v1.9.5):

[image]

After choosing "Diff against Current" from the context menu, you should see a message to the effect of:

> Displaying all changes between {commit_hash} and working copy

[image: After choosing to "Diff against Current" you should see a list of files that have changed, beneath the message "Displaying all changes between {commit_hash} and working copy"]

Comment: This one worked for me. Using Command, which is intuitive, did not.

Comment: "Diff against master" would be a great addition. If I select master and "diff against current" I see the reversed diff of the current feature branch.

Comment: You can also do this for tags

Answer (score 21):

You can also do this by ctrl + clicking the two <s>branches</s> commits you want to diff.

Answer (score 4):

On `macOS` hold the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key, click over first branch, later secondary click over the second branch and select `Diff Against Current` option on Popup Menu.

[image]

At the right Hand, you can see the difference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an External Diff tool. For example I am using Beyond Compare. After you set it as an external diff tool in sourcetree, you select both files you want to compare using CTRL and after that you press CTRL+D. As a result, Beyond Compare will be launched with both files ready to be compared.