# Why GitHub shows changes when compare two identical branches?

Tags: git, github

I have created test repository: https://github.com/Labutin/CompareBranches
Let's try to clone and compare two branches branch_01 and branch_02

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Labutin/CompareBranches.git
Cloning into 'CompareBranches'...
remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 7 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), done.

$ git diff remotes/origin/branch_01..remotes/origin/branch_02 --exit-code
$ echo $?
0
```

So, we have two branches which are identical.

But if I try to use Web UI to compare two branches https://github.com/Labutin/CompareBranches/compare/branch_01...branch_02 it shows 1 file changed.
Why? Whats wrong with Web UI? Maybe I have to modify URL?

Comment: If you use VS code, the GitLens extension can compare files between branches without caring of the commits ahead/behind or history of them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112526/how-to-compare-different-branches-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 8):

This question is really about GitHub—but we can use it to *construct* a question about Git.

After I clone your repository:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Labutin/CompareBranches.git
Cloning into 'CompareBranches'...
remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 7 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
```

I can view all of the commits in it:

```
$ cd CompareBranches
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 5707453 (origin/branch_02) Commit to branch_02
| * c0e3722 (origin/branch_01) commit to branch_01
|/  
* 0e9a4e3 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Initial commit
```

So there are three commits, whose actual (but abbreviated) names are `0e9a4e3`, `c0e3722`, and `5707453`.  The *remote-tracking name* `origin/master` refers to the first commit, and the other two remote-tracking names `origin/branch_01` and `origin/branch_02` refer to the other two commits.

If we ask Git to compare commits `c0e3722` and `5707453`, we see no difference:

```
$ git diff c0e3722 5707453
```

But if we ask Git to compare, say, commit `0e9a4e3` to commit `5707453`, we see that *these* two commits *are* different:

```
$ git diff 0e9a4e3 5707453
diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
index f00f3be..b183451 100644
--- a/README.md
+++ b/README.md
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
-# CompareBranches
\ No newline at end of file
+# CompareBranches
+commit1
```

Since commits `c0e3722` and `5707453` have the same content, comparing `0e9a4e3` to either one will show this same change.

#### The `git diff` command has special syntax

When we want to compare two commits, we can run:

```
git diff <thing-1> <thing-2>
```

and Git will compare thing-1 to thing-2.  The part inside the angle brackets can be anything that identifies a commit: a raw hash ID like `0e9a4e3`, or a branch name, or a remote-tracking name, for instance.

If we run:

```
git diff <thing-1>..<thing-2>
```

Git does *exactly the same thing:* it compares the two things.

**But**, if we use **three** dots instead of two:

```
git diff <thing-1>...<thing-2>
```

Git does something special.  Instead of comparing the two commits we named, Git finds a *third* commit.  In particular, Git looks for a *merge base* commit, from which both the named commits descend.  We see this in the `git log --graph` output above: the two tip commits both descend from commit `0e9a4e3`.  So that's the merge base, and therefore, with *three* dots instead of two, that's the commit Git uses on the left side of the comparison.

The right side is just `<thing-2>` itself.

As it turns out, GitHub is doing the same thing here, which is why GitHub's link has three dots in it: GitHub is mimicking the syntax of `git diff`, on purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Note the triple dot in the Github URL. Github is doing `git diff remotes/origin/branch_01...remotes/origin/branch_02`. `r1..r2` is subtly different from `r1...r2`.

`r1..r2` asks for all commits reachable from `r2` except those reachable by `r1`.

`r1...r2` asks for "*all the commits that are reachable by either of two references but not by both of them.*"

Let's look at these in your repo.

```
A - B [branch_02]
 \
  C [branch_01]
```

`git log branch_01..branch_02` gives us `B`. `branch_02` can reach A and B, but `branch_01` can also reach A, so this gives us `B`.

`git log branch_01..branch_02` gives us `B` and `C`. `branch_01` can reach `A` and `C`. `branch_02` can reach `A` and `B`. Both branches can reach `A`, so it is excluded.  We're left with `B` and `C`.

For more, see [Revision Selection, Double Dot and Triple Dot in Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection).

Comment: GitHub actually doesn't "do" the two dot comparison at all, it seems.

Comment: Looks like two dot doesn't work. Try https://github.com/Labutin/CompareBranches/compare/branch_01..branch_03
Branches are not equal.

Comment: @dhythhsba I think you're right. It looks like Github is interpreting `branch_01..branch_03` as a reference and defaulting the base to `master`. Rather than throwing an error because the reference doesn't exist, it's reporting no difference. For example, https://github.com/Labutin/CompareBranches/compare/aldkflakjfkjd