# How to compare the current branch with another branch in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio lets assume the following scenario:

1. Create a branch from the master.
2. Make some changes.
3. Commit.
4. Again make some changes.
5. Commit.

When we make a commit there are no changes displayed under the **Team Explorer > Changes**. If we didn't do the step 5 the **Changes** tab will display the current changes compared with the previous commit. I need to know how to compare current state of the branch(committed + uncommitted) with the original code(master branch).

Comment: Do you mean as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57833947/6309?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare different branches in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112526/how-to-compare-different-branches-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: The links provided are helpful for Visual Studio Code but not for Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Microsoft DevOps as your remote repository. DevOps has a way to compare branches. Under the "Repos/Branches" menus.

Example Heading:

Branch compare
Comparing "RevampTasks" to "Development"

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2019 (as asked)

- Open window Git Changes
- Click on Additional Operations

[image: Git Changes Window]

- Click Manage Branches

[image]

- Select the two commits/branches you want to compare (with ctrl+click)

[image]

- Right click on one of the selected commits and choose Compare Commits

[image]

- Now at the bottom right you should have a list of the files that have been changed and you can click on them to see the differences between them.

[image]

Comment: Good answer.  When viewing those differences, is there a shortcut key for jumping to the next difference?

Comment: I don't remember but with VS2022 yes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-browse-repository?view=vs-2022#compare-branches

Comment: Selecting two branches doesn't appear to be possible. If I right-click a second branch, it deselects the first one. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmmm. @Mike Hofer, I have to control LEFT click to select two branches.  I know the post says right click, but that does nothing for me but bring up a pop-up menu.  Try ctrl-left-clicking and see if that works for you.

Comment: Nope. No dice. We *are* talking about selecting multiple branches in the Repository window, right? (As shown in the pictures above?)

Comment: The answer was specific for VS2019, in VS2022 there is new features, have you checked the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-browse-repository?view=vs-2022#compare-branches ?

Comment: I don't use VS2019 anymore but the doc says: "Select the two commits/branches you want to compare (with ctrl+click)" then "Right click on one of the selected commits and choose Compare Commits". Maybe the issue is that you are trying to click the branch instead of the commit from the branch?