# Missing "Compare with Current Branch" menu option

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

According to [Microsoft docs - Browse Git repositories and compare branches in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-browse-repository?view=vs-2019#compare-branches), I should have a `Compare with Current Branch` menu option right after `View history`. However, I don't have them, in neither the branch picker nor the 'Git Repository' window.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019, Version 16.11.16. <s>[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41941917) suggests this feature was available since Visual Studio 2017</s> ***Edit:*** Reading again, looks like it's a different feature.

***Edit:*** I do get it with Visual Studio 2022 Community, Version 17.3.0, on the exact same clone. It's now named `Compare 'mybranch' with 'main'`. [This visualstudio blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-new-git-features-to-visual-studio-2022/#compare-branches) suggests it's a new feature, so maybe the documentation incorrectly attributes it to VS2019...

Comment: I think your repo has to be in Azure DevOps. See this one...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64057995/how-to-compare-the-current-branch-with-another-branch-in-visual-studio-2019

Comment: My repo *is* in Azure DevOps, though a locally-hosted one rather than dev.azure.com.