# Review Feature Branch Specific Changes Before Push To Master

Tags: git

I'm using git [basic branch/merge](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) to make feature changes.  Typically during development there are several local commits.  Some features take a fair amount of time complete so I periodically merge the master branch onto the feature branch so the feature branch stays somewhat in sync with master.

Once the feature is fully tested and ready to commit to master, I'd like to be able to review the changes specific to the feature branch that are not changes caused by periodically merging master.

Is there an easy way to see/review all feature branch specific changes before push to master (that aren't changes caused by periodically merging master)?

Comment: There are many ways. Are you using a git GUI of some kind (say, gitkraken) and/or a centralized git service like GitHub, Bitbucket, etc?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git visual diff between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912985/git-visual-diff-between-branches)

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're already up-to-date with master, since you already did merges for that, you can use `git diff` to show all modifications that branch makes:

```
git diff master..<your branch>
```