# Is it possible to compare multiple branches to one in git?

Tags: git, merge, branch, diff, git-diff

Would it be possible to compare Branch 1 and Branch 2 changes against Master in this scenario?

```
*   * Branch 2
|  /
|/ 
| * Branch 1
|/
* Master
```

Ideally this is something difftool would be able do.

Answer (score 1):

Not in one operation: comparing multiple branches with master would be a sequential process:

- comparing `Branch1` with `master`
- comparing `Branch2` with `master`

"[Showing which files have changed between git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23270231/6309)" illustrates (using [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) and [git difftool](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool))

```
git difftool -d master otherbranch
```

With:

```
-d
--dir-diff
```

> Copy the modified files to a temporary location and perform a directory diff on them. This mode never prompts before launching the diff tool.