# Git tracking remote branch

Tags: git

I have one problem, 
I have been reading about that but I am not sure which solution is correct and as of now I am unable to test which solution is the right one.
So, I am working on a remote branch, changing things, other people are working here too.
When I am done I want to push but other people already changed that branch and I can't do that. Whenever I do pull it want to merge the branch.
Is there any other way to get latest commits from branch without merging and then push my changes?

Comment: *Is there any other way to get latest commits from branch **without merging** and then push my changes?* why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to get latest changes and then push my own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the most up-to-date upstream branch, you can fetch it (no merge here) and create a temporary branch:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b  tmp origin/master
```

That way, you can switch back and forth between `tmp` and `master` (your own local branch), and compare their differences (in term [of file list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822859/6309)).

Note that you won't be able to push your changes without forcing a push and erasing the upstream history.

The best course of action would be to rebase your `master` branch on top of `origin/master`:

```
git pull --rebase
```

(A merge would occur there, but more importantly, your own commits would be replayed on top of the most up-to-date version of the upstream `master` branch)

Then you would be able to push your own changes.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I have checkouted on remote branch tmp, did some changes, now if I do git fetch i will not be able to push my changes? I have to do git pull --rebase and then I can push?

Comment: `tmp` isn't a remote branch: it is based on one, but it is a local branch. Just a marker to allow you to see what `origin/master` looks like. As for the rebase, it is mandatory if you want to push your commits: you don't even have to create `tmp`: you can fetch, and then rebase `master` or top of `origin/master`: that is what `git pull --rebase` does.