# How to list the modified files on a specific branch in GIT

Tags: git

I encountered a tricky problem. 
For instance I was working on the "**feature**" branch, after several commits and merges, the code delivered to the "**master**", and the diagram was like:

```
   ---A---B---C---D---I  master
       \   \     /   /
        E---F---G---H  feature
```

What I want to know is which files was modified on the "feature" branch.

I found this command: `git log --name-only --pretty=format:'' origin_branch..new_branch`
It seems it can give me the result, but the point is I must specify a proper range.

But after I study the manual, I don't know how to give a right range.

What I want to get is:

```
        E--- ---G---H  feature
```

According to gitrevisions (git help gitrevisions):

master..feature => none

master...feature =>

```
   ---.---.---C---D---I  master
       \   \     /   /
        .---.---.---.  feature
```

feature^@ =>

```
   ---A---B---.---.---.
       \   \     /   /
        E---F---G---.  feature
```

You can see none of which matches my requirement.

Really thank you if you can help me with that.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify, are F, D, I merge commits here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing which files have changed between git branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822811/showing-which-files-have-changed-between-git-branches)

Comment: The question looks similar but they are not. My problem is: The master..branch cannot give me the right range, you will get nothing if you use "git diff --name-status master..feature".

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I've updated it with a command chain which should work in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, the easiest way would be to find the commit on which `feature` deviated from master (in your case `A`). After this you can tell git to show you all commits on `feature` excluding merges and any commits after the "original" commit.

To find the commit `feature` originated from we can use this command chain; there might be an easier way, but I'm not aware of one:

```
git rev-list master --first-parent | grep "$(git rev-list feature --first-parent)" | head -1
```

This effectlivly lists all commits which are "only" on `master` by only following the *first parent* (ignoring the merged in commits) and compares them to the commits on `feature`. We use the first commit which occurs on both, that's the commit `feature` originated from.

Then we use this commit to list all commits on `feature`, ignoring merge commits and any commits which follow the "originating" commit.

```
git log feature --name-only --no-merges --first-parent --not $(git rev-list master --first-parent | grep "$(git rev-list feature --first-parent)" | head -1)
```

If you want to use this command more often I would suggest creating an alias.

Comment: With a test, it works and output what I want. Really thanks.

But the command is too complicated and I need more time to understand it.

Comment: @tricycle If you want I could extend my answer and go into greater detail. I didn't have a lot of time as I wrote this.

Comment: I think I understand how you did it. Firstly, It is the "--first-parent" eliminate the merge commit from the history. Secondly, find the very beginning of the feature branch. So, no detail is needed, it is clear to me. Except you have more things that I don't realized. Thank you very much.

Comment: @tricycle Actually first parent just takes care that git doesn't list the merged in branches for a merge commit. Usually `git log` and `git rev-list` will follow both parents of a merge commit and `--first-parent` ensures that it just follows, well, the **first** parent (which is the branch we merged the changes into). Maybe you meant to say that.