# How to see what kind of change was made to file in commit

Tags: git

I would like to see what kind of change was made to each file in a commit. That is to see whether a file was modified, added or deleted.

For example, this gives a list of all files changed in a commit:

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only <SHA>
```

It would be nice to have a similar list where there is also information for each file about the change: added (new), modified or deleted. How to see this information?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `git diff --name-status`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing which files have changed between two revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822811/showing-which-files-have-changed-between-two-revisions)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-status <SHA>
```

the output will be

```
A       src/addedFile
D       src/deletedFile
M       src/modifiedFile
```

Comment: thank you very much! git log -n1 --name-status <SHA> is what I need. I need only to get rid of the info that comes before the list of files (commit, author, date and commit message), which I can do with grep/sed or similar... or is there any way to show only the list of files?

Comment: Thank you all! This prints only the list of files with status: git show --pretty="format:" --name-status <SHA>