# How to show git diff --name-only between 2 branches for a specific module (or multiple modules) within a repo

Tags: git, module, git-diff

I am trying to work out a way to get git to show the list of "name only" changes between 2 commit points (be them tags or branches) for a specific submodule.

I can do this easily using [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) for a single repo by doing the following:

```
git diff --name-only commitPointA..commitPointB
```

(Here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822859/532489) that talks about this for reference purposes)

But this lists all the file changes for the repository that I am running the command within.

How can I refine the change list to only display the changes to a certain module, or a collection of modules within the same repo?

Comment: Define "module". Git knows about "files" as kept in "trees"; if you want  to diff a specific file or tree, simply add that to the `git diff` command (see the `-- <path>` argument).

Comment: @torek I meant a module as described in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/module/info. I will take a look at the path argument, thanks.

Comment: That particular form or style of module (treating a tree as the container for the collection) is one way to do modules, but not the only way.  (Though in the bad old days, we tended to have alternative words for sets of files that made up logical groups.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@torek pointed me in the right direction suggesting I look at the `<path>` argument. Here is what I did to get a refined list by module.

Changes within a single module...

```
git diff --name-only commitPointA..commitPointB ./moduleA
```

Changes within multiple modules...

```
git diff --name-only commitPointA..commitPointB ./moduleA ./moduleB
```

Its probably worth stating here that the module name simply represents the name of the root folder for that module within the repo.

That's it, simple in the end.

---

An alternative to specifying by path is to just pipe the output through `grep` and specify something you know you're really interested in like a module name (I know it sounds obvious).

Here is a simple example:

```
git diff --name-only commitPointA..commitPointB | grep 'module-name'
```

You could expand this to search for multiple values as well, just checkout the [grep man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) for more information.