# How to check how much a file changed from one branch to another in git?

Tags: linux, git, github, gitlab

I want to check that how much a file changed from one branch to another in git.

Comment: Lets hope and wait for answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing which files have changed between two revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822811/showing-which-files-have-changed-between-two-revisions)

Answer (score 1):

```
git diff branch1 branch2 -- file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions:

**(1)** See number of difference files immediately.

```
git diff branch_foo branch_bar --name-only --oneline --numstat | wc -l
```

**(2)** Export to text file, then count number of lines.

```
git diff branch_foo branch_bar --name-only --oneline > result.txt
```

then open file result.txt, count number of lines.

**For example**

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot.git
cd spring-boot
git diff master heads/remotes/upstream/gh-6030 --name-only --oneline --numstat | wc -l
git diff master heads/remotes/upstream/gh-6030 --name-only --oneline > result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my working flow, probably can give you some ideas.

Normally I have branch `master` and `develop` and have an alias in my shell, named `gd`

```
alias gd="echo master diff:; git diff --name-status master develop"
```

This helps me to list all the files that have changed between the branches (master and develop).

Next, if I would like to only see the differences between two files I use:

```
 git d develop master -- file.txt
```

Notice the `d` instead of using `diff`:

In this case `d` in an alias in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    d = difftool
[diff]
    tool = vimdiff
```

This helps me to use `vimdiff` so that I can easily see the changes, by using the `[diff]` options, you can add your tool of preference, hope this can help you or give some ideas about how to extend the `.gitconfig` to simplify repetitive tasks.