# Github accidental changes in two files

Tags: git, github

I am new to GitHub and am currently learning to work on a public repository. I have forked the repository and have two branches created (master and testing). I work on the testing branch.

Accidentally I changed two files of the remote repository that were not supposed to be changed and created a pull request. Of course, my request was discarded because of those changes and I was asked to revert the changes from those two files.
I tried to revert the changes using many methods available on the internet and also some of my own. (like manual copy-paste from git), git revert and others.

Now, when I run `git diff <testing> origin/master` , I do not see the two forbidden files. Does that mean there's no difference in them ?

Can someone explain to me how to check differences in particular files from remote repository ? 
And can someone also explain how to revert forbidden changes and create a new pull request.

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: To check the difference please try this commend git diff -- testing origin/master

Answer (score 0):

Since you told us that you created a pull request with unwanted modifications to two files, I will assume therefore that you have already committed those changes.

If the commit in question is the most recent commit in the `testing` branch then you can try resetting those two files to the immediately prior commit and then amending the commit:

```
git checkout testing
git checkout HEAD~1 -- path/to/file1.ext
git checkout HEAD~1 -- path/to/file2.ext
# git add, if needed
git commit --amend
git push --force origin testing
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `git push origin +testing` to force update the github repo?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : Can you tell me why I don't see those two files when I run.
'git diff <testing> origin/master'

Comment: @GauraangKhurana I seldom run `git diff`, but according to [this very highly voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822811/showing-which-files-have-changed-between-two-revisions), the syntax you should be using is this: `git diff --name-status testing..origin/master`

Comment: Hey, I tried to run your commands and got stuck.
Earlier I had done a rebase by mistake and had to reset it. 

Now I cannot run the command stated here  - 'git commit --ammend' 

This shows my errors. Can you guys please help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47037433/stuck-while-trying-to-undo-a-rebase