# How do i get a list of files changed in a pull request via the git command line tool?

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I need a git command that will list all of the changed files in a pull request.

I only want the file path of the changed files, no extra info.

I've tried: git diff --name-only but that doesn't return anything for a PR.

Answer (score 6):

Pull Request is a GitHub feature and not a native Git command. However, if you have the source and target branch names, you can get the files changed using,

```
git diff --name-status firstbranch..yourBranchName
```

[Showing which files have changed between two revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822811/showing-which-files-have-changed-between-two-revisions)

Comment: Just a quick note. [Pull request is a git command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull), but it doesn't do what most people think of.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, but it's `git request-pull` not `git pull-request`. :-) A bit of hair-splitting to some, but to my ears, it's like the difference between "go play" and "play Go", or something like that.

Comment: @torek exactly. I thought I’d include it for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GitHub API. For example,
https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/488/files

`octocat` is project owner, `Hello-World` is project name and `488` is pull request number. You can modify these values for your pull request. This request returns a JSON array of modified files and `filename` attribute gives you file path.

Comment: Note that there is a limit to number of results using this API (300 files).  So for large pull requests, you'll need to fetch and use git instead.

Comment: Note: Responses include a maximum of 3000 files. The paginated response returns 30 files per page by default.
source: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-pull-requests-files