# GitHub/GitLab REST API - Get diff between two branches

Tags: github-api, gitlab-api

We want to get a difference between two GitLab/GitHub branches through REST API. We saw Git supports a command to do that but it seems they don't support for REST API. Is there any API support for this?

```
git diff --name-status firstbranch..yourBranchName

git diff --name-status origin/develop..origin/master
```

[Showing which files have changed between two revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822811/showing-which-files-have-changed-between-two-revisions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GitHub has dedicated URL (non-REST) for [comparing branches](https://help.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/comparing-commits-across-time#comparing-branches).
Example:

https://github.com/octocat/linguist/compare/master...octocat:an-example-comparison-for-docs

Same for GitLab:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/compare?from=master&to=master

Although it can be [different from a git diff](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/26649).

---

The REST API for GitHub would be: "[Compare two commits](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits)"

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/compare/:base...:head
```

> The response also includes details on the files that were changed between the two commits.
>   This includes the status of the change (for example, if a file was added, removed, modified, or renamed), and details of the change itself.
>   For example, files with a renamed status have a `previous_filename` field showing the previous filename of the file, and files with a `modified` status have a patch field showing the changes made to the file.

For GitLab: [compare branch API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#compare-branches-tags-or-commits)

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/compare?from=master&to=feature
```

Comment: Thank you for your information. That is what I need.

Comment: Hi VonC, do you know how to compare branch API for GitHub?

Comment: @TonyTran It is https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits: Both `:base` and `:head` must be branch names in `:repo`. In other words, if  `:base` and `:head` are *branch* names instead of commits *SHA1*, ... you are comparing branches.

Comment: How would you do this with CodeCommit ?

Comment: @AntoineDussarps AWS CodeCommit? Not sure (it should be its own question). May be [`aws codecommit get-differences`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/codecommit/get-differences.html), as in `aws codecommit get-differences --repository-name <repository-name> --after-commit-specifier <branch-name-1> --before-commit-specifier <branch-name-2>`.

Answer (score 1):

As @VonC says

BUT Watch out for a gotcha.

If you are working from a list of all commits in a PR.
Your result for each commit in the list will include `commit_hash['commit']['url']`

It has format
`https://api.github.com/repos/myorg/myrepo/git/commits/7358c0d4bd18a4b7b6f30a3e3e7b34xxxxxe22e9`

If  you use this url to call a single commit you *won't* get the files!

You need to remove `/git` from the url, or use the `commit_hash['url']` which is correct