# git how to compare two branches of the same repository

Tags: git, compare

I have two branches one is ok the other introduces a problem.  I want to download both branches to separate folders so I can use "Beyond Compare" to analyse and find the problem.

I've create two folders on the local file system using the commit ID of the working and broken branches how do to this, the broken commit is 114ae931 and the working commit is 0647841c.

Comment: Compare as in "diff"? Would `git diff 114ae931 0647841c` work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing which files have changed between two revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822811/showing-which-files-have-changed-between-two-revisions)

Comment: No, not really because I want to use Beyond Compare to do the comparison, using git with difftool results in using vi which isn't a nice experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've set difftool to bc, you can use the following command:

```
git difftool 114ae931 0647841c
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$ git diff branch1..branch2
```

edit: look at this : https://devconnected.com/how-to-compare-two-git-branches/

Comment: Beware though, this is not a symmetric difference, if `branch2` has commits unknown to `branch1`, their diff won't show up with your example. Consider using `...` operator

Comment: Yes, done that already,but there is so much of it and its not as easy to follow as using Beyond Compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the SHA

```
git diff <sha1> <sha2>
```